# Is there an intuitive reason that explains Fermat's Last Theorem?

Tags: alternative-proof

> In number theory, Fermat's Last Theorem (or **Fermat's conjecture**) states that no three positive integers a, b, and c satisfy the equation $a^n + b^n = c^n$ for any integer value of $n$ greater than 2.

I know that there are math intensive proofs for this. But is there a more *holistic* reasoning as to why this isn't possible?

Comment: another related question [Is there a simple way to illustrate that Fermat's Last Theorem is plausible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786226/is-there-a-simple-way-to-illustrate-that-fermats-last-theorem-is-plausible)

Comment: Incidentally, the standard proof of FLT **is** quite holistic, i.e., the solution to this specific (and in itself quite irrelevant) problem was obtained be stepping back and looking at the larger picture. It took *a lot* of stepping back, and the picture is *a lot* larger.